# Archive Page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, archive

I want to know how to make an archive page like instantshift has made.. link below..

> http://www.instantshift.com/archive/

I have made everything but don't know the query to specify the orderly archives listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Viper Bond's Clean Archives for a similar effect: http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/clean-archives-reloaded. I like that the jQuery effect only shows when you activate the plugin in a page.

You could also use `<?php wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>` as found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

Don't forget to not leave wordpress.stackexchange.com lonely too!

Comment: don't want to use a plugin...:(

Comment: Then you can achieve the same effects with `<?php wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>` -- that is the query you are looking for. WP has good documentation on it.

Comment: Yeah, I have done it through archives functions, with some other attributes... was a head ache.. but thanks anyway